# nslookup returns different IP than $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']

Tags: ip, nslookup

Without knowing much about system administration, here is in short what I noticed:
running nslookup the-site.com returns some IP
but
running $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] on that site returned different IP.

Could someone give a possible explanation of why is this difference?

Longer version:
Why I'm asking this? I was trying to white-list a clients IP form my security plugin (on WordPress), but even after white-listing IP I got from nslookup he still seemed blacklisted. I then tried white-listing the IP returned by $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] (executed on his site) and that did the trick.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is a bit unclear. A white-list isn't necessary unless you have introduced some blocking in the first place. And you haven't told us where you are blocking connections and what criteria that is based on.

Comment: What is your web server and what is its configuration? How is the server set up?

Comment: Hi @kasperd, that's not important for my question. I use a wordpress plugin for security and blacklisitng/whitelisting among others. Question is pretty clear, why the other site that tries to connect to my site (why and how doesn't matter) has different IPs with nslookup and $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'].  Tero Kilkanen, my server config has nothing to do, other site's server seems to have, and as I'm not an expert, I would like just some simple suggestions as in the accepted answer. Thanks for your interest guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP server variable `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` is set by the webserver on which your PHP code is executed.

There are many situations in which the actual webserver that runs your code will have a different ip-address from the one associated with the DNS domain name in the URL:

- The site is behind a CDN like CloudFront.
- The site is behind a load-balancer
- The site is behind a reverse proxy server
- etc.